# Cannot assign source to jar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using a java jar file in my eclipse project. Beside this, I have a "normal" folder including the sources of this jar. Now I created a folder "lib" in my eclipse project, added the folder with the source files into it and attached this folder to the jar file. But everytime I want to open the code definition by clicking on a class (ctrl + click) I get the message "assign source code"... What is the mistake?

Comment: is folder with source files a source folder?

Comment: No, it is a simple folder: Project - New... - Folder. And there I created a folder named "lib" and put all the java files in it (using the correct directory structure of course)

Comment: just make the folder with source files as source folder !It helps !

Comment: Please vote and mark answer as correct if it is :) ! it helps and encourages to move further !

Comment: How can I mark answer as correct, it is only a comment ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does you JAR file only have .class files in it?  If so you will need to Attach the Source i.e. .java files.  I don't know if you have the .java source files in your possession.

If you do have the .java files (or they're in the JAR and aren't being picked up) you can use the "assign source.." dialog to point Eclipse to the location of the source files.  If you don't have the source files, but want to see it then consider installing an Eclipse decompiler plugin e.g. [JD-Eclipse](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse)

Comment: In the jar there are only class-files. In my folder I try to attach are only java-files. I use the same folder structure like inside the jar file...

Comment: Yes so if you have the .java files, but they're in a different location to the JAR you should be able to use the dialog to point Eclipse at the source files (provided structure matches).  You can always add the source files to the JAR if you're struggling.